# Is there a way to edit XML values?

Tags: android, xml, colors

OKay guys, I want to know if something is possible in Android. Basically, I want my App to be able to have different color themes, examples being Red, Blue and Green. In the settings Action, the user would be able to choose from those three in radio button form. Now, one way to change the colors of the app would be to load all of the buttons, backgrounds etc of each activity and change all their colors, but that would be very inefficient.

What I wanted to do was make an XML value file with two colors, one for background colors and one color for buttons and such, and then assign all elements' colors to take their color from that XML file. Now would there be a way to change the value of the XML file while the app is running so that the colors can be changed on the fly?

If not, is there an easier way to change the colors of my app?

Answer (score 0):

You will surely not write this into the XML file.

But you can save the user's choice in the SharedPreferences. And when the user opens the app, you assign this color value for example to the specific element of your choice.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

**Themes**

Create separate theme for each color. Apply colors to all views that require particular color.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) you will find details about defining styles and themes.

**Restart Activity**

In button click listener implement restarting current activity.

Till API10:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("style", R.style.another_style);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Since API11:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("style", R.style.another_style);
Activity.this.recreate();
```

I am not sure if passing new style in API11 example will work. If not, you can try store new style in `onPause()` method or `onSaveInstanceState()` and then read it in `onCreate()`.

**Use style**

Inside `onCreate()` method always look for "style" property and apply before setting view for activity. e.g.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super(bundle);
    int style = getIntent.getIntExtra("style", -1);
    if (style != -1) {
        setTheme(style);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```